# How to interpret low fit of bifactor SEM model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics

I am trying to evaluate the psychometric properties of a questionnaire instrument using bifactor SEM. A bifactor model with five group factors has the best fit, and this model has “good” RMSEA and SRMR. However, CFI and TLI are low (around .85). The psychometric coefficients derived from this model (e.g., omega hierarchical) paint a pretty dismal picture of how the instrument is performing. So, how do I interpret this? I can see three possible conclusions and would appreciate your help sorting them out:

1. I trust the model despite its lower CFI/TLI and conclude that the
   instrument is psychometrically problematic
2. I distrust the model due
   to its lower CFI/TLI and conclude that I don't know what the
   instrument's psychometric performance is
3. I assume that a good
   instrument “should” fit a bifactor model and take its lower CFI/TLI
   as evidence of poor psychometric performance

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the bifactor fit compare with a single factor?

Comment: @JeremyMiles For a single-factor CFA, fit is worse than it was for the bifactor model (CFI = .452 and RMSEA = .095).

Comment: Question about how the model is being run:  ¿is the software you are using including/excluding correlations between the different latent factor sets?

Comment: The latent factors are all uncorrelated.